# Jenkins - Plugins not installing and jobs and features are missing after upgrade.

Tags: plugins, jenkins, installation, upgrade, installed-applications

I'm using latest Jenkins (v 1.590) LOL, but Jenkins official site say: 1.588. I'm 200% sure that I did see 1.589 and 1.590 few days back on Jenkins official download site(when I wanted to upgrade Jenkins to newer version).

This is what I see at the bottom of my Jenkins instance page.

```
Page generated: Nov 19, 2014 12:07:51 PMREST APIJenkins ver. 1.590
```

Now, the issue I'm facing is: Since I upgraded few of the plugins and Jenkins itself recently, some of the jobs are missing (I see this can happen during upgrades but upgrading to latest Jenkins should fix it and I'm two steps ahead of what Jenkins has on their official site, right):

1. I go to Manage Jenkins, Manage Plugins, Go to Available tab, check mark bunch of plugins to install (Artifactory, Maven project plugin etc ) and restart Jenkins using Jenkins GUI interface (which happens automatically once plugins are downloaded/installed in Jenkins GUI). After the restart, I do the same to see whether the plugin is now showing under "Installed" tab or not, but to my luck, it's still showing under "Available tab" and is NOT listed under "Installed" tab. If I open an existing job's configuration OR create a new job, the features available due to installed plugins are **NOT** visible i.e. if I installed Maven Project Plugin, I don't see an option to create a Maven style(2/3) project job while creating a new job.

I see valid .**jpi** files for respective plugins in plugins folder in JENKINS_HOME and there are some .pinned files as well. I have tried this a couple of times but the plugins are not visible once installed. Installation doesn't give any error during the whole operation.

**Jenkins system log** file (upon Jenkins restart) is attached (NOTE: Use slow download button to see/download this log file).

[Download at SpeedyShare](http://speedy.sh/x6vd8/Jenkins.System.Log)
or
[code]http://speedy.sh/x6vd8/Jenkins.System.Log[/code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the plugins permissions and expanded folders.

If you see under the plugins folder, you'll see .jpi or .hpi files (Jenkins jpi and Hudson hpi).

If I have awesomeplugin.jpi then there will be a folder called awesomeplugin.

Using Slav's hint, I ran bunch of checks and found out of 70+ plugins that I had installed, few of them somehow got "root" and "root" as their owner and group for their .jpi files and corresponding folder.

Now, The best solution one can try (the safest approach) is to chown -R yourvalidjenkinsuser:yourvalidgroup * and chmod -R 755 * as root. Before doing this, stop/shutdown jenkins.

I went even a step further, I first took backup of config files / whole jenkins JENKINS_HOME folder. Then I went to plugins folder and remove all .jpi corresponding folders using root account or as the owner of those folders (NOTE, I didn't delete the .jpi files). Then, I ran the above two commands (chown/chmod) and started Jenkins.

**OUTCOME:**

1. when I'm going to Jenkins > New item (to create a new job), Shenzi, all different types of jobs options are showing up (which included the Maven2/3 type job which I found got missing and few others like "Multi-configuration project" and Multijob Project job type.. all were missing and now they are showing up.
2. OK, I also checked one of the old job, went to its job's configuration and Shenzi!! I now see all the features there i.e. (Promoted Job plugin feature "Promtoe builds when.." check box. This feature which I configured sometime back, got missing but now it's showing up again.
3. Few of the Maven jobs that I created in past with Maven Release Plugin and Release Plugin POC work had bunch of steps in it. I found there was nothing in the Build step (after this whole mess), but after the above solution, I now see everything is back. I can see the configurations and build steps populated as they were set.

I hope this can help someone facing similar issue.

Still, I don't know why my Jenkins version is 1.590 (which Jenkins updated recently in automatic fashion) and Jenkins site today says, their latest Jenkins artifact is version 1.588 (seems like a mystery).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "valid .hpi files", did you actually test that they are valid? You should be able to rename them to `.zip` and extract as a valid archive. An issue I face a lot is the network layer filtering system that we have in the office. It intercepts Jenkins's calls sometimes with the filtering system's login page, instead of whatever internet resource was being loaded.

If your `.hpi` files are not valid zip archives, open them in a text editor, and see if they are in the form of an html page/response of some kind.

Comment: Actually the files are .jpi (instead of .hpi). I will check that. Don't you think if they are not valid zip file format then Jenkins won't even start?

Comment: OK, I checked all .jpi files (under plugins directory). They are all valid. Running the following command at plugins folder, gives "0 -- file -- 0" (where file is the actual .jpi plugin filename). Command I ran: for f in `ls -1 *.jpi`; do file $f 1>/dev/null 2>&1;rt1=$?; unzip -l $f 1>/dev/null 2>&1;rt2=$?; echo "$rt1 -- $f -- $rt2"; done

Comment: Did you get a chance to see what could be an issue by seeing the system log that I attached to my post. It seems like one of the plugin (either not compatible OR messing the whole Jenkins).

Comment: Indeed my script to pull plugins was not following redirect responses (needed `curl -L`), so I was getting an HTML redirect page in my `.hpi` files. Thanks!